# sql dateiff comparing age to hiredate

Tags: sql, date, select, datediff

First time using Stack Overflow, all classes have been thrown online and I am horrible at online class.

the question is simple I need to gather the information on employees who were 35 years or younger when they started with the company using datediff.

my code looks like this

```
Select EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName, BirthDate, HireDate,
datediff(year, BirthDate,HireDate) Age 
from Employees
where age<=35;
```

without using "where" it will post the age of the people when they started. I am trying to now display the age column I created to post everyone who was less than or equal to 35 years or younger. however, i get a syntax error with age. obviously it does not exist in the sql database. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is fine as an approximation, but it will not actually produce the person's "age" in the accepted sense.

Answer (score 0):

The `where` clause cannot refer to an alias defined in the `select` clause (the latter is executed *after* the former).

You need to repeat the expression in both clauses:

```
select 
    e.*, 
    datediff(year, BirthDate,HireDate) Age 
from employees e
where datediff(year, BirthDate,HireDate) <= 35
```

Or you can use a deried table (subquery or common-table-expression) - but it is less efficient, and seems like overkill for this simple expression:

```
select *
from (
    select
        e.*, 
        datediff(year, BirthDate,HireDate) age 
    from employees e
) e
where age <= 35
```